# OutOfMemory Exeption VSTO Add-in Office 2016 64bit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, ms-office, vsto

As the Title suggests I get an OutOfMemory Exeption in my VSTO Add-in in Excel 2016-64bit.
That happens when I update a Pivottable with the Table.Update() method which is provided by the VSTO Add-in by Microsoft.
My Machine has 16 GB RAM and the Process Memory in VS 2017 shows that only about 270 MB are used.
It works when I refresh the PivotCache wiht PivotCache().Refresh(); but that takes about 20 minutes which is
way too long.
AdditionalInformation would be that the Memory Exception occurs instantly when I hit my Update Button.
For a real memory exception I would expect the process Memory to rise over time till it is full and then throw an exception.

Any Ideas or suggestions would be nice. At this point I have no Idea where to look.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The issue is hard to reproduce in a minimal solution but apparently i am not the only one with that problem.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/18a6abc5-c390-41a9-8db7-206dbd86c509/getting-out-of-memory-exception?forum=exceldev
This person had the same problem in 2014 an the issue remained unresolved.
It seem like a rare bug in VSTO Addin.
I programmed a workaround:
Takes about 1 min so its fine since i need to update the Pivot Table once or twice a day.

```
  try
   {
     //some other code
     Table.Update();
     //Some ohter Code
   }
    catch(OutOfMemoryExeption)
    {
      Table.Pivotcache().Refresh();
      faildAny = true;
    }
```